# Display a string for a number of times

Tags: php

I have a Select box which is filled with numbers, I want when I select a number for example 5 to print a string 5 times.

This is the code I tried so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .centrer
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        font-size:24px;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <select name="nombres">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

   <div class="centrer">
    <?php
        $s = "Hello World! <br/>";
        for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
            echo $s;
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where or how should it be printed?

Comment: I want it in the same page where the Select box is

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

We can easily do this using javascript.
But you need printing your string in php.

while using javascript we dont need to load a page.
But in PHP we need to load a page each time selecting select box. 
Because PHP is server side.
Javascript is client side.

cheers...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkIt()
{
    var getNum = document.getElementById("numb").value;

    //this_file.php ... im specifying for just. you specify this full code in any of file and specify the whole url path
    location.href="this_file.php?countIt="+getNum;
}
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .centrer
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        font-size:24px;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <select name="nombres" id="numb" onchange="checkIt();">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

<?php
if($_REQUEST["countIt"])
{
    $displayTimes = $_REQUEST["countIt"]; 
}
?>
   <div class="centrer">
    <?php
        $s = "Hello World! <br/>";
        for($i=0; $i<$displayTimes; $i++)
            echo $s;
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okey thanks, it worked but there is a ptoblrm that when I select the "1" Value it does anything, and also when I select other value the selected value in the select box still the value "1" and I have another question isn't there any other way to do this without using JS only by using PHP ?

Comment: Use requested count value as selected value in select box using Javascript. And this functionality is possible just using PHP. but we should reload page on every new select in select box.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to send back the server the value from the form. From there, you can render the page as you see fit.